# Launching an Electron app on Windows restart

Tags: windows, gruntjs, electron

So I've built a Windows installer for my Electron app using https://github.com/electron/grunt-electron-installer.

I'm not sure how to launch my app on system start up, like when the user reboots their computer. I suspect it's something I need to do on `--squirrel-install` but I can't find any documentation on how to do so.

Ideally I would provide a menu option for the user to enable/disable this behaviour.

Comment: Can you please help me with the steps you followed to create an electron auto-launch app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a app to be run on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156897/getting-a-app-to-be-run-on-startup)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using electron on Windows/MAC, there is an existing api which you can use to easily auto start your electron APP：

```
        _electron.app.setLoginItemSettings({
            openAtLogin: true,
            path: _electron.app.getPath('exe')
        })
```

the reference can be found here:
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a few different ways. The method i used to do this on a windows OS was to use the node [winreg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg) module, this allowed me to add a registry key that launched that app on startup. I use this method on a settings window in the application that has some user settings:

```
function setKeyValue () {
    var regKey = new winreg({
        hive: winreg.HKCU,
        key: '\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run'
    });
    regKey.set('Your_Application_Name', winreg.REG_SZ, '"' + process.execPath + '"', function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          //notify user?
        }
    });
```

I also have the opposite method that removes the reg key `regKey.remove` if the user disables the app launch on startup.

Alternatively, i have recently seen this node module: [auto-launch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch) ,this allows you to set whether the app launches on startup on Mac, Windows and Linux, and therefore might be more useful for you.

Comment: @mike Does this solution allow the application to launch on boot, or only on user login? If not, do you know any way to make the app start at boot?

Comment: @PhilippeHebert Hi, I'm not sure since it was Jamie that answered this question but I do know that the package `auto-launch` works quite well and runs app at boot. Here's a thread on it: https://github.com/electron-archive/grunt-electron-installer/issues/115

Comment: Hi Mike! As it turns out, it seems auto-launch, and the new api setLoginItemSettings both only launch the app when the user logs in. This means that for servers, the app will not start until someone comes to do manual maintenance. Any thoughts @teimaj?

Comment: Hi @PhilippeHebert, did you manage to start the app on boot?

Comment: Hi @Racker; no - we've opted for a python executable running as Service instead. If that's a viable avenue for your team, then look into pyinstaller & pywin32